# Rails parse csv separtor ¦

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, parsing

i have csv file with strange format

```
2783¦Larson and Sons
967¦Becker Group
333¦Rolfson LLC
```

I have tried to do this

```
CSV.foreach("#{Rails.root}/csv_files/suppliers.csv") do |supplier|
  p supplier[0]
end
```

but have got a string `"2783¦Larson and Sons"`

How to separate values? 
For example will return

```
supplier[0] #=> "2783"
supplier[1] #=> "Larson and Sons"
```

Comment: You can specify the delimiter via `CSV.for_each(filename, col_sep: '¦') do ...`. See [`CSV.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) for available options.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect `CSV` to know how to handle this weird input? You should explicitly specify the encoding and the column separator.

```
CSV.read("#{Rails.root}/csv_files/suppliers.csv",
      encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1,
      col_sep: "\xC2\xA6".force_encoding(Encoding::ISO_8859_1)) do |supplier|
  puts supplier.inspect
end
#⇒ [["2783", "Larson and Sons"],
#   ["967", "Becker Group"],
#   ["333", "Rolfson LLC"]]
```

Comment: Why do you expect the CSV file to be ISO 8859-1 encoded? And where does `\xC2` come from?

Comment: @Stefan I just showed an approach, I assume OP knows better what encoding to use. `\xC2` came from reverse engineering :)